# Java driver throws error

Tags: java, arangodb

I'm running into an error when trying to use `ArangoDB (2.7.0)` with Java driver `2.6.8`. Wondering if I'm missing something which is obvious.

Moreover, it would be really great if error below report the name of the collection that it is not able to found, unlike Oracle's "table not found" and spend lot of time figuring out which table is missing when using large stored proc.

```
CollectionEntity vCollection = arangoDriver.createCollection("vertexCollection", new CollectionOptions().setType(CollectionType.DOCUMENT));
CollectionEntity eCollection = arangoDriver.createCollection("edgeCollection", new CollectionOptions().setType(CollectionType.EDGE));

List<EdgeDefinitionEntity> edgeDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();
EdgeDefinitionEntity edgeDefinition = new EdgeDefinitionEntity();
edgeDefinition.setCollection("edgeCollection");

List<String> from = new ArrayList<>();
from.add("vertexCollection");
edgeDefinition.setFrom(from);

List<String> to = new ArrayList<>();
to.add("vertexCollection");
edgeDefinition.setTo(to);

GraphEntity graph = arangoDriver.createGraph("myGraph", edgeDefinitions, null, true);

VertexEntity<Object> v1 = arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("myGraph", "vertexCollection", new Object(), true);
```

---

The `arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex(...)` throws as given below:

```
2015-10-14 07:42:59.930 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [REQ]http-POST: url=http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/sphere/_api/gharial/myGraph/vertex/vertexCollection?waitForSync=true, headers=null, body={}
2015-10-14 07:42:59.940 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [RES]http-POST: statusCode=404
2015-10-14 07:42:59.941 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [RES]http-POST: text={"error":true,"code":404,"errorNum":1203,"errorMessage":"collection not found"}
Exception in thread "main" com.arangodb.ArangoException: [1203] collection not found
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:262)
    at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:314)
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalGraphDriverImpl.createVertex(InternalGraphDriverImpl.java:332)
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalGraphDriverImpl.createVertex(InternalGraphDriverImpl.java:294)
    at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.graphCreateVertex(ArangoDriver.java:4455)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/arangodb/QJZHLUBcz4w), following statement was missing!

edgeDefinitions.add(edgeDefinition);

It works now.